# DNS server isn't responding windows 8.1

Tags: networking, dns

I have been having a very weird problem the last week with my laptop.  For some reason I lose connection to the DNS server. I have figured out that if I change the DNS server to Google's, `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` I get a connection to the DNS server, but after a random amount of time, 30 min to 2 hours, it stops again. I can then set my DNS to *automatic*, and it will work for another 30 min to 2 hours again.

I am running windows 8.1, 64 bits.

Does any one know a fix for this?

[image: Troublesooting window]

[(Link to full-size image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcuXw.png)

Ipconfig /all

```
C:\Users\KasperRune>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Lilith
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Intern
al Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-42-57-44
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9a5:2b0e:98cc:e0aa%13(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.160(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 536876381
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-F9-34-A6-F0-DE-F1-7D-9E-29

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 4:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 02-24-D7-E7-E6-7C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-24-D7-E7-E6-7D
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : CC-AF-78-E5-F3-58
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connecti
on
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : F0-DE-F1-7D-9E-29
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter WiFi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-24-D7-E7-E6-7C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.11(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 30. juni 2014 20:21:43
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 2. juli 2014 20:42:52
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.241
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.241
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.241
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{A411004F-AEC7-46A6-B46E-A7A4F2574A72}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{2BD7CA35-6FC1-45D6-9811-758527DB5FDE}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #12
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

C:\Users\KasperRune>
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `ipconfig /all` ?

Comment: I have up it in the first post

Comment: It looks like your comptuer, specifically your WiFi and ethernet adapters are still using your router/modem as the DNS server, check that google's DNS servers: `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` are set on your **router** as the default DNS servers.

Comment: As i said i have to switch DNS server in my networks adapters settings every 30 min to 2 hours, this ipconfig /all was while i had it to automatic dns

Comment: Try setting those Google's DNS servers to be the ones that are distributed via dhcp from your modem. I.e. Change then on your modem rather than only on your computer.